# Extracting Factors Causally Related to Landslides from DEMs (SRTM)

Tags: python, dem, slope, srtm

I have the SRTM dataset, and I've managed to write some python code to show elevation and slope heatmaps. The code runs fine, and the elevation data is reliable (I checked some points from the web), but the slopes that I'm getting seem to be really off. I checked my code and it doesn't seem like there's any logical error there.

I'm using python's richdem library for Terrain Calculations: https://github.com/r-barnes/richdem

And my code for calculating slope is here: http://pastebin.com/1PxWMJ4A.

Here's an example elevation map on the left and the corresponding slope map on the right (degrees). (they're a bit small so feel free to open in a new tab).

[image]
[image]

The region I've chosen is super flat (with the exception of the river and the hills up north).

Why is the resulting slope map so noisy?

Is it supposed to be like this?

If I need to take a measure of the slope around this area (say, to assess landslide hazard), how am I supposed to do this without having my metric be subject to all the wonkiness in the slope map?

Additionally, here's a global slope map that I generated (again, in degrees). So much of the earth's surface has a slope of >50 degrees!

What is going wrong?

[image: global slopemap]

For example, the following image is a place near the Himalayas where landslides are common.

[image]
[image]

How can I get any useful information if I'm being blinded by slopes >= 80 degrees all the time?

Am I just calculating the slope incorrectly?

I did calculate the rise-run slope for the same area. (see below) It looks like it's better, and I'm willing to use it, but I want to understand why the slope in degrees is being wonky.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you reproject your DEM from WGS84 (horizontal units = decimal degrees) to an appropriate projected CRS that uses metres as the horizontal units.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Slope algorithms assume the spatial coordinates (horizontal units) are the same as your vertical units.  The vertical units of your SRTM DEM are metres (above sea level). SRTM DEMs are provided in the WGS84 CRS which uses  decimal degrees (longitude, latitude) coordinates, you need them in metres, hence you need to reproject your data to a projected CRS (coordinate reference system) that uses metres.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a single, focused question following GIS SE guidelines. You can always open a second question.

Comment: @user2856 thanks. Do you know of any python libraries or resources where I can find code for such a conversion, or will I have to code it myself?